# React native bridge is sometimes nil in swift module

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

I have a swift module created, which starts listening on a GCDAsyncUdpSocket when a connect method is called from swift

```
@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {
  var bridge: RCTBridge!
  var socket: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!

  func methodQueue() -> dispatch_queue_t {
    return dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.greatapp", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
  }

  @objc func connect(resolver resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: methodQueue())

    //...start listening, etc
  }

  @objc func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromAddress address: NSData!, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject!) {
    bridge.eventDispatcher().sendAppEventWithName("got_msg", body: nil)
  }
}
```

I've also created a private implementation

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(connect resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock *)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock *)reject)

@end
```

However on occasion `bridge.eventDispatcher()` unwraps to nil and it is unable to broadcast the event.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Github issue led me to the solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3454.  Turns out this was only happening on reload.  One needs to implement `RCTInvalidating` and then clean up any dangling references in `invalidate`.  This allows ARC to cleanup your native module properly and reinstantiate `RCTBridge`

```
@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate, RCTInvalidating {
  var bridge: RCTBridge!
  var socket: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!

  func invalidate() {
    self.socket = nil
  }

  func methodQueue() -> dispatch_queue_t {
    return dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.greatapp", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
  }

  @objc func connect(resolver resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: methodQueue())

    //...start listening, etc
  }

  @objc func udpSocket(sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket!, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromAddress address: NSData!, withFilterContext filterContext: AnyObject!) {
    bridge.eventDispatcher().sendAppEventWithName("got_msg", body: nil)
  }
}
```